# Logging data raspberry pi cat feeder, I can't seem to make it work! Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have done a cat feeder with a RPi that works with the following script and it seems that the logger worked only once and it's stopped logging to the file feedings.log.

Is there anything I need to change in the logger or any improvements that can make it function better. It's my first time using a logger in my code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import logging

#Logging data into a separate file called feedings.log

logging.basicConfig(filename='feedings.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

# function move specifies the movement of the servo there are more movements 
# at the end of the script

def move():
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

# GPIO definitions for pin number and PWM
servoPin = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPin, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(servoPin,50)

# servo starts at 2.5 which is best for this servo not 0
p.start(2.5)

# feeding number of times
feed = 3

try:
  while True:
    now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if now == '10:00:00':
        for x in range(feed):  
            x = move()
            logging.debug("Morning feeding is done")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        continue
    elif now == '17:00:00':
        for x in range(feed):  
            x = move()
            logging.debug("5 o'clock feeding is done")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        continue
    else:
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

# The code stops when keyboard interrupts and cleans GPIO

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  p.stop()
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

I would appreciate any help!